# No error message but everytime I run my code, it executes and exits

Tags: node.js

Here is my app.js code. Absolute beginner here. When I run $node app.js it executes and exits instead of showing it to the localhost:8000

```
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');



function renderHTML(path, response) {

fs.readFile(path, null, function(error, data) {

    if (error) {

        response.writeHead(404);

        response.write('File not found!');

    } else {

        response.write(data);

    }

    response.end();

});

}

 module.exports = {

handleRequest: function(request, response) {

  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

  var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

  switch (path) {

      case '/':

          renderHTML('./index.html', response);

          break;
         case '/login':
         renderHTML('./login.html', response);
           break;
          default:

          response.writeHead(404);

          response.write('Route not defined');

          response.end();
           }
    }

 };
```

My server.js code

```
 var http = require('http');

 var app = require('./app');

 http.createServer(app.handleRequest).listen(8000);
```

What am I doing wrong? I am not getting any error messages, am I missing a library? I have been coding with VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App.js just exports some functions.  You should be running

```
   $ node server.js
```